# How does one create a distributed data loader with PyTorch's TorchMeta for meta-learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, meta-learning

I was trying to create a pytorch distributed data laoder with torchmeta but it failed with a deadlock:

```py
python ~/ultimate-utils/tutorials_for_myself/my_torchmeta/torchmeta_ddp.py

test_basic_ddp_example

ABOUT TO SPAWN WORKERS (via mp.spawn)
-> started ps with rank=0
-> rank=0
-> mp.current_process()=<SpawnProcess name='SpawnProcess-1' parent=54167 started>
-> os.getpid()=54171
device=device(type='cpu')
----> setting up rank=0 (with world_size=4)
---> MASTER_ADDR='127.0.0.1'
---> 57813
---> backend='gloo'
-> started ps with rank=2
-> rank=2
-> mp.current_process()=<SpawnProcess name='SpawnProcess-3' parent=54167 started>
-> os.getpid()=54173
device=device(type='cpu')
----> setting up rank=2 (with world_size=4)
---> MASTER_ADDR='127.0.0.1'
---> 57813
---> backend='gloo'
-> started ps with rank=1
-> rank=1
-> mp.current_process()=<SpawnProcess name='SpawnProcess-2' parent=54167 started>
-> os.getpid()=54172
device=device(type='cpu')
----> setting up rank=1 (with world_size=4)
---> MASTER_ADDR='127.0.0.1'
---> 57813
---> backend='gloo'
-> started ps with rank=3
-> rank=3
-> mp.current_process()=<SpawnProcess name='SpawnProcess-4' parent=54167 started>
-> os.getpid()=54174
device=device(type='cpu')
----> setting up rank=3 (with world_size=4)
---> MASTER_ADDR='127.0.0.1'
---> 57813
---> backend='gloo'
[W ProcessGroupGloo.cpp:684] Warning: Unable to resolve hostname to a (local) address. Using the loopback address as fallback. Manually set the network interface to bind to with GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME. (function operator())
[W ProcessGroupGloo.cpp:684] Warning: Unable to resolve hostname to a (local) address. Using the loopback address as fallback. Manually set the network interface to bind to with GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME. (function operator())
[W ProcessGroupGloo.cpp:684] Warning: Unable to resolve hostname to a (local) address. Using the loopback address as fallback. Manually set the network interface to bind to with GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME. (function operator())
[W ProcessGroupGloo.cpp:684] Warning: Unable to resolve hostname to a (local) address. Using the loopback address as fallback. Manually set the network interface to bind to with GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME. (function operator())
----> done setting up rank=0
----> done setting up rank=2
----> done setting up rank=3
----> done setting up rank=1
about to create model
about to create model
about to create model
about to create model
done creating ddp model
about to create torch meta data loader
about to get datasets
here
done creating ddp model
about to create torch meta data loader
about to get datasets
done creating ddp model
about to create torch meta data loader
done creating ddp model
about to create torch meta data loader
about to get datasets
about to get datasets
here
here
here
```

why does this happen?

whole code: https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils/blob/master/tutorials_for_myself/my_torchmeta/torchmeta_ddp.py
ref: https://github.com/tristandeleu/pytorch-meta/issues/116

---

```py
#%%
"""
test a basic DDP example
"""
from argparse import Namespace

import torch
from torch import nn

import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# from meta_learning.base_models.learner_from_opt_as_few_shot_paper import get_learner_from_args
from uutils.torch_uu.models.learner_from_opt_as_few_shot_paper import get_learner_from_args
from uutils.torch_uu import process_meta_batch
from uutils.torch_uu.dataloaders import get_distributed_dataloader_miniimagenet_torchmeta, get_args_for_mini_imagenet
from uutils.torch_uu.distributed import print_process_info, print_gpu_info, setup_process, move_model_to_ddp, \
    cleanup, find_free_port


def get_dist_dataloader_torch_meta_mini_imagenet(args) -> dict[str, DataLoader]:
    dataloaders: dict[str, DataLoader] = get_distributed_dataloader_miniimagenet_torchmeta(args)
    return dataloaders

def run_parallel_training_loop(rank: int, args: Namespace):
    """
    Run torchmeta examples with a distributed dataloader.

    This should distribute the following loop:
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(dataloader['train']):
        print(f'{batch_idx=}')
        spt_x, spt_y, qry_x, qry_y = process_meta_batch(args, batch)
        print(f'Train inputs shape: {spt_x.size()}')  # (2, 25, 3, 28, 28)
        print(f'Train targets shape: {spt_y.size()}'.format(spt_y.shape))  # (2, 25)

        print(f'Test inputs shape: {qry_x.size()}')  # (2, 75, 3, 28, 28)
        print(f'Test targets shape: {qry_y.size()}')  # (2, 75)
        break

    Note:
        usual loop for ddp looks as follows:

    for i, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        if rank == 0:
            print(f'{loss=}')

        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()  # When the backward() returns, param.grad already contains the synchronized gradient tensor.
        optimizer.step()
    """
    print(f'-> started ps with {rank=}')
    args.rank = rank
    print_process_info(args.rank)
    print_gpu_info()
    args.gpu = rank
    setup_process(args, rank, master_port=args.master_port, world_size=args.world_size)

    # get ddp model
    print('about to create model')
    # args.Din, args.Dout = 10, 10
    # model = nn.Linear(args.Din, args.Dout)
    model = get_learner_from_args(args)
    model = move_model_to_ddp(rank, args, model)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(args.gpu)
    print('done creating ddp model')

    # can distributed dataloader
    print('about to create torch meta data loader')
    dataloaders: dict[str, DataLoader] = get_distributed_dataloader_miniimagenet_torchmeta(args)
    print('done created distributed data loaders')
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 1e-4)

    # do training
    print('about to train')
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(dataloaders['train']):
        print(f'{batch_idx=}')
        spt_x, spt_y, qry_x, qry_y = process_meta_batch(args, batch)
        outputs = model(spt_x)
        loss = criterion(outputs, spt_y)
        if rank == 0:
            print(f'{loss=}')

        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()  # When the backward() returns, param.grad already contains the synchronized gradient tensor.
        optimizer.step()

    # Destroy a given process group, and deinitialize the distributed package
    cleanup(rank)

def hello(rank: int, args):
    print(f'hello {rank=}')

def ddp_example_torchmeta_dataloader_test():
    """
    Useful links:
    - https://github.com/yangkky/distributed_tutorial/blob/master/src/mnist-distributed.py
    - https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html

    """
    print('test_basic_ddp_example')
    # args = Namespace(epochs=3, batch_size=8)
    args = get_args_for_mini_imagenet()
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        args.world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    else:
        args.world_size = 4
    args.master_port = find_free_port()
    print('\nABOUT TO SPAWN WORKERS (via mp.spawn)')
    # mp.spawn(hello, args=(args,), nprocs=args.world_size)
    mp.spawn(run_parallel_training_loop, args=(args,), nprocs=args.world_size)
    print('mp.spawn finished\a')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('')
    ddp_example_torchmeta_dataloader_test()
    print('Done\a')
```